# Change UITabelView animation for rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, animation, cell

As there are number of different animation in cocoa to present UIViews, but have'nt seen any animation for cells. so can we change UITabelView animation for rows? if so plesae share sample code..

Comment: Describe more exactly what you want to change.. which animation!?

Comment: as user scroll down/up the tabel , tabel should be scroll with cell animation.. i have seen this implementation in some apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guy i think you are going to learn all cocoa in this night.. :) @Muz you can change cell animation using [ADlivelytableview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/adlivelytableview).. Simply import this class and as

```
ADLivelyTableView * livelyTableView = (ADLivelyTableView *)self.mTableView;

livelyTableView.initialCellTransformBlock = ADLivelyTransformFan;
```